# Bounds on sum of reciprocal of logarithm of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

Are upper/lower bounds known for the following quantity?

$$S(n,a)\stackrel{\triangle}{=}\sum_{p_k \leq n}\frac{1}{(\log p_k)^a}.$$

I am mainly interested in the case, $a=1$. I suppose with the approximation $p_k\approx k \log k$ it is going to be roughly equal to the logarithmic integral, but I hope that there is something better known to the experts.

In fact, if that's the best known result, how would one go about proving rigorously that it is asymptotic to $\mathrm{li}(n)$?

Comment: Just use the prime number theorem and partial summation.

Comment: You could also e.g. split the sum at n/(log n)^100, I think.

Comment: Note that $p_k$ is asymptotic to $k\log k$, not $k/\log k$. Also, there is no $a$ in your question, so the comment regarding the $a=1$ case makes no sense. At any rate, please open a new question if necessary (I marked this one as duplicate).

Comment: @GHfromMO: I understand why you marked as duplicate. Apologies, there was a typo, now fixed. Also, I had not found upon search the other answer, which answers the case $a=1.$ Any info on $a\neq 1$ would be appreciated.

Comment: The case of $a>0$ can be treated in much the same way as $a=1$ (see the answer to the "duplicate" question). One gets that the sum is asymptotic to $\frac{n}{(\log n)^{a+1}}$. Note also that $\log 2$ is positive, so there is no need to omit the $p_k=2$ term.

Comment: @GHfromMO:Regarding answer for $a>0$ in general, fair enough, thank you.